# How to imagecopy GIF source file to transparent PNG destination file without losing background color?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, png, gif

I am following the example from the PHP documentation, "Adding watermarks to images using alpha channels" except my destination image is a transparent PNG file and my stamp image is a GIF image. The problem I encountered is that my stamp GIF image loses its background color, black, and becomes transparent in my final image. My final image extension should be the same as the source file, GIF.

```
<?php
    $source = 'path_to_file/source.gif';//190x34 size image with black background
    $trans_img_dir = 'path_to_file/blank.png';
    $final_image = 'path_to_file/final.gif';
    $BLANK_IMG = 200;

    //create transparent image
    $imcreate = imagecreatetruecolor($BLANK_IMG, $BLANK_IMG);
    imagecolortransparent($imcreate, imagecolorallocatealpha($imcreate, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    //imagealphablending($imcreate, false);
    //imagesavealpha($imcreate, true);  
    imagepng($imcreate, $trans_img_dir);
    imagedestroy($imcreate);

    $blank_mark = imagecreatefrompng($trans_img_dir);

    $im = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    $sx = imagesx($im);
    $sy = imagesy($im);

    imagecopy(
        $blank_mark,
        $im,
        $BLANK_IMG/2 - $sx/2,
        $BLANK_IMG/2 - $sy/2,
        0,
        0,
        $sx,
        $sy
    );

    imagegif($blank_mark, $final_image);
    imagedestroy($blank_mark);
    imagedestroy($im);
```

?>

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLUwL.gif)

[destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R059d.gif)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a code sample ;-)

Comment: Can you provide the images too?

Comment: @Mark Setchell source and destination images uploaded.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You want to put a source image (which is a GIF?) onto a destination image (which is PNG and you haven't provided? or have you?) to make an output image (which is a GIF? and I don't know how it looks?) What is the image you have labelled as `destination`? Your words and code imply the destination image is a PNG and it is transparent yet you have labelled a GIF as the destination. Can you clearly explain what you want to do, showing 2 start images and 1 result image please?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Yes, that is correct. I want to put a GIF source image onto a destination image that is a PNG transparent image file and then save that as a GIF. The PNG transparent image file is not provided because it is created after my variables are declared (I wouldn't be able to upload a third image due to my lack of reputation anyway!). The output image is the destination image provided and is labelled as 'destination.' The final image should look tike the destination image but with the black background that is seen in the source image.